# jquery hover over areas on image map ie7/ie8

Tags: jquery, hover, area

I have an imagemap and am using the following

```
 $('area').hover(function(e) {
```

The problem is ie7 and 8 do not detect the hover event for the area tag. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: It should work fine with `mouseover`.

Comment: IE doesn't understand HTML5 tags. Are you using Modernizr?

Comment: what html5 tag? Area? should be ok http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp/ I have added html5shiv but not through modernizr just an ie conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple demo in an attempt to reproduce your problems but it seems to be working. I used IE9 but changed browser mode through the integrated developer tool to test IE7 and IE8.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/400" width="400" height="400" alt="Kitten" usemap="#areamap" />

<map name="areamap" id="areamap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,300,300" href="#top" alt="Top" id="area1" />
</map>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('area').hover(
    function(event) { console.log(event.type, this.id); },
    function(event) { console.log(event.type, this.id); }
);
```

​
You are welcome to try it out yourself at http://jsfiddle.net/Xcm46/